# Magento 2.2 : Execute customer grid reindex after customer gets locked

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, event-observer, customer, indexing

My question is basically on the title, I've been trying to find some event being dispatched when an user gets locked for password attempts but so far I haven't find anything, maybe I'm coming at this the wrong way but,

**What I really need is to execute the customer grid indexer reindex when an user gets locked?**

I tried looking at the `app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Locks/Unlock.php` class but I haven't found a clue.

I would really appreciate your help in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any event by default when the customer gets locked.

The `app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/Customer` 's `isCustomerLocked()` defines if the user is locked or not.

I suggest you add a after plugin on this function and dispatch a custom event after checking the return value, and on that event you can run your indexer code. Or you can just add the reindexer code in plugin itself.